# Use redis for log caching: Is it possible to create an eviction policy that evicts to PostgreSQL?

Tags: c++, postgresql, caching, logging, redis

I have a newly written system (written in C++) where I expect lots of logging to be done, at least in the beginning until the system proves reliable. I'm planning to store the database messages to a PostgreSQL server, but for efficiency, I'd like to cache in Redis first, where I write to Redis, and then if the messages exceed some size, I dump them to the persistent database, where they can be navigated later.

I [read about LRU caching](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) of redis and it seems suitable, however it seems that LRU caching is more oriented towards reading data and not writing. In other words, the scenario described there sounds like if I want to read something from a persistent database, and in order to avoid reading (accessing) that persistent database many times, I take that value and write it in redis cache and use it repeatedly. But I'd like to do the opposite. My logging system will write log messages to redis, and then I'd like them to be "evicted" to PostgreSQL in a predefined schema.

Is there a way for me to write a Redis plugin that will make this possible? I don't seem to find any literature or examples on this.

PS: Please feel free to suggest a better mechanism for log-caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want `write efficiency`, I suggest `leveldb` or `rocksdb`, both are `Log-Structured-Merge-Database (LSM)` design, which has excellent write performance and also good read performance.

   [Google Leveldb](https://github.com/google/leveldb)

   [Facebook Rocksdb](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb)
2. If you want use `redis` and `postgres`, I think you can use redis as a `job-queue`。
   Write your `log-message` to the queue, and setup some `worker` to retrieve the `log-message` from the queue and write to `postgres`.

   In this case, you may consider:
   [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org)

   Or implement a `job-queue` yourself with redis `List`: using `LPUSH` to store `log-message` and `LPOP` to retrieve `log-message` and then write them to `postgres`.

Comment: I gather that it's not possible to use LRU with postgres, not even with a plugin... thanks for the info. If no better answer appears, I'll accept this one.